# How do you indicate an element is moveable by keyboard arrows?

Tags: website-design, web-app, keyboard, drag-n-drop

I am building a drag and drop interface where elements can be moved by a mouse or by the keyboard arrows. How should I 'tell' the user these elements are moveable using the keyboard?

Any idea or a link to a similar website is appreciated.

Comment: Keyboard could support more rich functionality: arrows, SHIFT+arrow, CTRL+arrow, CTRL+SHIFT+arrow, etc. In this case it's better to provide some instructions.

Answer (score 2):

I once used the same (mouse and keyboard) in a serious game (elearning). I guessed that most of the users would start with mouse interaction. By presenting arrows (left/right/up/down) around the draggable object i expect that some users (that would appreciate the keyboard interaction) would try to use the keyboard arrows. 
Although I didn't get the chance to try it out with user testing...

Answer (score 1):

You could try changing the cursor to the **cross cursor** to indicate the element is draggable. See image below:

[image]

For the keyboard shortcuts, using a rounded square, with the key inside is usually a good indicator. **Soundcloud** displays their shortcuts like below:

[image]

To make even more clear to the user the options for moving the element, you could use [onboarding](http://sixrevisions.com/user-experience-ux/onboarding-techniques-examples/), which basically shows the user how to use the app the first time they log in, in a short and snappy way. Read more [here](http://sixrevisions.com/user-experience-ux/onboarding-techniques-examples/).